# Passing updated elements from JS thread to Shadow Thread

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

React native renders UI on screen using three threads:

- JS thread
- Shadow thread (Bridge)
- Main thread

Shadow thread is using Yoga engine to translate flexbox-based layout into a layout which native host can understand.

What my question is, does Shadow thread receives whole DOM tree, after reconciliation is done, and all elements from DOM are rerendered on Main thread, or is it reconciliation done in JS thread, and only changed elements are passed to Shadow thread, and, after transpiled, they are further passed to Main thread?